# Regex matching a space a digit and 8 characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a string containing,

a space

any number of digit

a space

1-8 characters - (alphanumeric and special characters)

example,

```
 01 Stack
```

This is what i tried,

```
\\s\\d+\\s[^.]{1, 8} - i tried here except for .,
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: is it possible to include all characters, here i have used except '.'

Comment: `\S` is for everything except whitespaces. `[^ ]` is for everything excpet space.

Comment: What are the special characters?

Comment: What happens when you tried this regex?

Comment: special characters - any characters. no exception

Comment: If you mean `any character`, then don't restrict to symbols.  For example, are you including or excluding whitespace?  In short, do you mean any thing except whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, to catch (and restrict to) the punctuation and alphanumerics: `\s\d+\s[\p{Punct}\p{Alnum}]{1,8}`; wrap it all in `^...$` if you want the begin/end line anchors.

If "any number of digits" means 1 or more digit, then the pattern above is fine.  If it means "zero or more digits", then the `\d+` needs to become `\d*`.

As an aside, the pattern `[^.]` will match anything that's not a period.  It includes a bit too much, I think, and excludes a bit too much.  So I'm opting for the more specific pattern `[\p{Punct}\p{Alnum}]`.

See [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Comment: nicely done.  i never looked Punct in regex.  Print also would do

Answer (score 2):

Try `\\s\\d+\\s[^.]{1,8}`? It looks like the only problem here is a superfluous space.

Also, `\\S` is for everything except whitespaces. `[^ ]` is for everything excpet space. `.` is for everything.

Comment: Downvoter, please add a comment to point out your reason so that I can improve my answer.